# NullPointerException Android

Tags: android, sqlite, nullpointerexception, android-database

I am getting NullPointerException and I couldn't fix it. Could anyone please have a look at my code to see what the problem is and how to fix it. Thanks in advance.

DatabeseDEO.class

```
            public class DatabaseDEO  {
    private DatabaseHelper DbHelper;
     public DatabaseDEO(Context context) {
            DbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
        }

        public DatabaseDEO() {

        }

        public ArrayList<String> getToSpinner() {
            ArrayList<String> list=new ArrayList<String>();
            SQLiteDatabase db = DbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
            db.beginTransaction();
            try
            {

                String selectQuery = "SELECT code FROM "+ Currency.NAME_TABLE;
                Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
                if(cursor.getCount() >0)

                {
                    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

                        String currency= cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("code"));
                        list.add(currency);

                    }


                }
                db.setTransactionSuccessful();

            }
            catch (SQLiteException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
            finally
            {
                db.endTransaction();

            }

            return list;
        }
    }
```

AddWallet.class

```
public class AddWallet extends AppCompatActivity {
Spinner currency;
DatabaseDEO db = new DatabaseDEO();
        ArrayList<String> list= db.getToSpinner();
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.currency_spinner, R.id.text,list);
        currency.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

}
```

currency_spinner.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="5sp"
        android:paddingBottom="10sp"
        android:paddingTop="10sp"

        >

    </TextView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Error

```
              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.martin.xxx/com.example.martin.xxx.AddWallet}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase Database.DatabaseHelper.getReadableDatabase()' on a null object reference
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
               Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase Database.DatabaseHelper.getReadableDatabase()' on a null object reference
                  at Database.DatabaseDEO.getToSpinner(DatabaseDEO.java:32)
                  at com.example.martin.xxx.AddWallet.onCreate(AddWallet.java:41)
                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6664)
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

Comment: If my answer helped you mark it as Correct answer, to mark the question as solved. If there not solved please request more info

Answer (score 1):

First of all as naming convention rename the *DbHelper* to *dbHelper*

Solution:
you have to constructors

```
    public DatabaseDEO(Context context) {
        DbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    }

    public DatabaseDEO() {

    }
```

first one you initialize the databaseHelper and the second one you don't initialize it.

In **AddWallet** you call the empty *Constructor* so the **DatabaseHelper** is not initialized you have to call the second constructor and delete the empty one to not wrongly call it again.